# Why is there a different behavior for quoted parameters when in crontab?

Tags: cron, quoting

Case scenario:

```
$ echo "1,2,4" | grep -v [0-9]
[No results, as expected]
```

But, when doing it via `cron`:

```
$ crontab -l
[...]
* * * * * echo "1,2,4" | grep -v [0-9] > /tmp/debug.dump
[...]
$ cat debug.dump
1,2,4
```

The solution (or maybe workaround, I don't know) :

```
$ crontab -l
[...]
* * * * * echo "1,2,4" | grep -v "[0-9]" > /tmp/debug.dump
[...]
$ cat debug.dump
[No results, as expected]
```

I would like to understand the issue rather than just solving and forgetting it.

Why did double quoting solve this?

Note: This is FreeBSD v10.3.

Comment: what shell is the crontab running, and what shell is that at your command line?

Comment: The shell is Bash, @thrig .

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, were you able to find a single-digit file in the home directory?

Comment: Indeed, @JeffSchaller . And it was `0`. Your answer seems correct. Thanks you. Upvoted, of course.

Comment: Outstanding; would you please click the check mark so the system sees this question as answered? Thank you!

Comment: Of course I will, @JeffSchaller. With no hurry, but the best of the answers that fit will be accepted. I prefer to allow some time for more answers or editions, precissions and comments to help evaluate the existing answers. Rules don't oppose to this behavior of me, and many users re-edit their answers even weeks after they wrote them. The info will still be there, even without the acceptation mark, so it will still be useful as a Wiki. Thus I see no reason to hurry up. (P.S: the system already sees this question as answered)

Comment: I’ll trust you to remember, then! I don’t have anything to add or change in the answer, unless there’s anything I can clarify for you.

Answer (score 4):

There's a file named 0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 in the home directory of the user running this cron job. The shell expands the unquoted `[0-9]` parameter to be that filename (say it's `0`); since there are no `0`'s in the input, the `grep -v` "succeeds" and prints nothing.

When you were testing, you were in a different directory (one that did not have a single-digit filename). Double- (or single-) quoting the parameter prevents the shell from expanding that glob, allowing grep to see it as a range.